# BLAS.dgemm method multithreading compute error

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, openblas

When I use spark mllib multi-layer-perceptron model to predict a vector, I found that the same vector gives different result sometimes in multithreading. I read the source code and found it is based on the BLAS lib. I made some test code for BLAS in multithreading.

I use BLAS dgemm utils to compute a matrix, the same matrix data gives different results when using multithreading.

My test code can be found on [github](https://github.com/wangyixiaohuihui/blas). In the test code, I make some artificial test data. To test it using Windows 10, add blas dll file in java class path.

When I use only one thread to run:

```
blas.dgemm(transa, transb, m, n, k,alpha, a, _a_offset, lda, b, _b_offset, ldb,beta, c, _c_offset, ldc)
```

the result is the same when running repeatedly. But using 5 or more threads to run the same data, 
`blas.dgemm` gives different results. This is confusing, why does the same data in `blas.dgemm` give different results?

Using Windows 10, add `netlib-native_system-win-x86_64.dll` to java class path.

Comment: I made some quite large grammatical changes, please change/revert back if there is anything that I missunderstood.

Comment: thanks.  I will pay close attention to grammar errors in  future.

Answer (score 0):

it might have concurrency problems  .array c (same object in the heap) is being changed by all threads synchronously.if a and b arrays are read only inside dgemm function.then no need clone of them

```
 @Override
 public void run() {
       double[] aa=a.clone();
       double[] bb=b.clone();
       double[] cc=c.clone();
     try {

        BLAS  blas =  BLAS.getInstance();
        blas.dgemm(transa, transb, m, n, k,
                alpha, aa, _a_offset, lda, bb, _b_offset, ldb,
                beta, cc, _c_offset, ldc);

        System.out.println("c.rows:"+ m + "   c.cols:"+n
                + "   c.data:"+ Arrays.toString(cc)
                + "   c._c_offset:"+_c_offset
                + "   c.ldc:"+ldc);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```